# Over an Artin algebra, does Gorenstein projective and Gorenstein flat modules coincides?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

In general, Gorenstein projective and Gorenstein flat modules have no obvious relations.
But I find that nobody discusses Gorenstein flat modules when the ring is an Artin algebra. So I believe that they are the same thing under this condition. Can anyone give me an explanation of this thing? Thank you very much!